# Are there clustering algorithms which require a human as an oracle?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, active-learning

Are there data clustering algorithms which by definition require human judgement as part of the algorithm? What I mean is that once in a while the algorithm presents the human operator (or any other species of operator) with a query of whether some objects (not necessarily from the original data set) should be grouped into the same cluster. The human operator serves as an oracle for the algorithm, and drives it towards a meaningful clustering.

It seems that such algorithms should exists, because different clustering algorithms usually optimize different target functions which depends on parameters, and on the one hand the user should choose an algorithm and parameters based on her goal, but on the other hand it is common with clustering problems that the user doesn't know in advance what he is looking for.

I tried Google searching for such algorithms, using key words that I thought might be related (for example, "human in the loop", "oracle", "agent", "semi supervised", "human judgment"), but so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: Well supervised learning, such as GLM, is kind of what you are describing - except that the user intervene at the very beginning of the process (the clustering the algorithm is starting with) -

Comment: Reinforcement_learning uses repetead feedback to improve the result. Although the feedback does not neccesarily come from a human, it possibly can. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning

Comment: @Riff What I'm looking for is an algorithm that decides what questions to ask the oracle, where on the one hand it tries to ask a small amount of questions, an on the other it tries to get the most information from the agent. Thus for example it may decide to ask a question about data which it generated (and does not belong to the data set) since an answer might provide more information. And also the answers to previous questions may influence which questions the algorithm asks next.

Comment: Then your Google is broken. https://www.google.com/search?q=semi-supervised+clustering

Comment: @Anony-Mousse semi-supervised clustering is something similar but different, where there is prior information about a subset of the data, given in advance. Am I correct? This is different from letting the algorithm decide, based on the data itself, which information it needs.

Comment: If you want active variants: https://www.google.com/search?q=active+semi-supervised+clustering e.g. "semi-supervised clustering with user feedback". Your Google is really bad...

Comment: The actual question is: is there any data where this works and is used, or does everyone simulate only?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, All you had to say is that these are called active algorithms.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Indeed that's another interesting question, but let the question askers decide what they want to ask

Comment: @Lior I think it's highly unlikely you will ever find an algorithm with those specs... Generally we want clustering algorithms to be as unsupervised as possible. However, I think you can emulate the 'human-in-loop' behavior by considering human inputs as restrictions to the solution. For example: if the algorithm is not very confident about clustering together two specific data instances, it could ask the human for their opinion, which would guide the algorithm in the task.